# GCP ETL pipeline failure - BQ to BQ migration

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm facing an issue or rather a challenge which I haven't been able to figure out yet. And thought that I might need help in setting it up the right way, any leads will be highly appreciated.

I'm very familiar with AWS but recently migrated to GCP and been tasked to setup the ETL flow, apologies If I cause any confusions in explaining the flow ahead.

To give a overview or sought of summary, this is how currently our pipeline is setup :

I've a production bucket, say *abc_prod*,  where app data is being populated in parquet, few to name are :

- abc_prod / installed_apps /
- abc_prod /contacts /
- abc_prod / location /

1. On daily basis parquet files are added in warehouse (GCS) in respective bucket/folders mentioned above
2. **GCS to BQ :** Python script reads the parquets from GCS and loads it to BQ in "inc" database with the help of the following code :

   ```
    bq_client = bigquery.Client()
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.PARQUET

    # Write truncate will overwrite existing data
    job_config.write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"

    # Executes BQ query job in background without waiting for its result
    job = bq_client.load_table_from_uri(src_uri, 
                                        table_ref, ### Reference to table say location_inc, contacts_inc, etc
                                        job_config=job_config)
   ```
3. **BQ to BQ :** Final step , the same python script reads the above BQ table and *appends* it in another database called "main" with the help of following code snippet :

   ```
   bq_client = bigquery.Client()

   job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(destination=table_id, ### Reference to main table say location_main, contact_main, etc
                                        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND")

   query_job = bq_client.query(query, job_config)
   ```

Now, the above pipeline executes without any failures for ***contact*** and ***installed_apps***

The concern here is ***location*** , For ***location*** until 2nd step everything executes smoothly. The parquets are read and write truncated in BQ "inc" database. On third step, although the code gets executed, but the data from "inc" DB is not appended into "main". The code produces No error or any kind of warning that could lead me debug ahead. Hence, I'm not able to figure out the exact cause behind this. I had used `allow_large_results=True` as a parameter for `QueryJobConfig` but still not able to populate "*location_main*".

One thing I noticed is that If I try it on few chunks of ***location*** parquets , it gets populated. It will be a big help, if anyone could provide me some insights. I've been thinking along these lines - is *location_main* failing to populate due to large volume of data, or is it something to do with inconsistent data types in parquet, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check if the `inc` table was populated? Also, you can try to run only the `query` of second step directly in the console to see the output

Comment: Yes , as I mentioned that till second step it is fine. location_inc is populated. Let me check running the query for main table directly like you say. I will update here. Thanks.

Comment: I'm able to run that query. In console I got the dataset. Also, in python by using *bq_client.query(query).to_dataframe()* I got the dataframe

Comment: Have you checked in the logs from [Cloud Logging in BigQuery](https://towardsdatascience.com/bigquery-3-simple-ways-to-audit-and-monitor-your-dabatase-1cf09027f0de)?

Comment: Also adding a `try... catch` block could help to troubleshoot your issue, as reffered on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57280504/13171940)

Comment: Thanks guys for all the help , I had resolved it. I will add solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to figure out that some parquets had extra / unexpected column. At the time of creating schema for master, it was created on the basis of column that were available at that point of time. I found out that we can handle column addition / relaxation in `QueryJobConfig` by adding parameter `schema_update_options` which holds 2 options ['ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION', 'ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION']

E.g :

```
    job_config = \
    bigquery.QueryJobConfig(destination=table_id,
                            write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
                            schema_update_options=['ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION','ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION'])
```